# libavdevice.dylib is the wrong version, how do I update it?

Tags: version, dylib

I am running osx 10.9 mavericks and unfortunately DaVinci Resolve no longer works. I think it has a possibility of working as the error message I get is this:

> Dyld Error Message:
>
> Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Libraries/libavdevice.dylib
>
> Referenced from: /Applications/DaVinci Resolve.app/Contents/MacOS/Resolve
>
> Reason: Incompatible library version: Resolve requires version 54.0.0 or later, but libavdevice.dylib provides version 52.0.0

I tried downloading ffmpeg and replacing the dylib but that didn't work. Anybody know how to update it?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a package management tool [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) or [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/). My preference is Homebrew.

Alternatively you could install ffmpeg from source and get all the associated libav libraries